# Get large amounts of data from windows service on remote machine with no public IP (dotNet)

Tags: c#, wcf, signalr

I have been thinking of the best solution to query the data from remote machines with internet access but without public IP

I have a plenty of intel NUC machines and the AWS-based server machine. I have ASP.NET MVC application deployed on the server

User will open the particular page, press the button and then he needs to see the data from the remote intel NUC machine on the page.

My understanding is that I can use WCF duplex mode to access the clients from the server and have the windows service (WCF client) istalled on the client machine and communicating with the hardware. But the thing is that the hardware SDK gets data in chunks and the read time couuld be up to 20 seconds (200 chunks) for example, and I want the user to immediately see the data as soon as the subsequent chunks is ready. Not sure if WCF is the best

The second solution came into my mind is the following: by pressing the button the server will send the SignalR command to the client. After receiving the command the client will start fetching the data and send to the server using POST-request or whatever. Then the server will store the data in some in-memory storage such as Redis and the UI client will get the data and show.

Could you please advice? Am I crazy?

Comment: Why not fetching the data on a regular interval and cache it in redis? You can serve the client with the data from the cache

Comment: I thought about it, this will make the system much simpler. I just don't want to load the internet connection all the time, because we pay for the data transferred. And also we plan to have 1000+ clients